# android layout listview with edit text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-edittext

In my project need to make layout  listview with edit text

[image]

please suggest me how i can make this kind of layout

Thanks In Advance

Any Help Is Appreciated

Comment: [Try here](https://www.google.com/search?q=create+custom+listview+android&oq=create+custom+listview+android&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.5527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) or [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vogella.com%2Ftutorials%2FAndroidListView%2Farticle.html&ei=HL4xU9u0HcT4yAH6t4GgDg&usg=AFQjCNEmKxSOQWTEdnIteMT1duTBuc2Xsg&sig2=-ckuSP7bOp2uaBynXYMhlw&bvm=bv.63587204,d.aWc) first

Comment: See this example http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/

Answer (score 0):

Use following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

      <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/mylinear"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

    </LinearLayout>

 </ScrollView>


     <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/group4ff"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/vazgecff"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight=".30"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:onClick="cagir"
             android:text="vazgec" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/kaydetff"
             android:layout_width="0dp"
             android:layout_weight=".70"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:onClick="cagir"
             android:text="kaydet" />
     </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity.java

```
public class Form3 extends Activity {

LinearLayout[] llx ;
TextView[] tx ;
EditText[] ex ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form3);

    DBHandler db = new DBHandler(this);
    ArrayList<Siparis> listem = db.getSiparis();
    db.close();

    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
    llx = new LinearLayout[listem.size()];
    tx = new TextView[listem.size()];
    ex = new EditText[listem.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < listem.size(); i++) {
        llx[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        tx[i] = new TextView(this);
        ex[i] =new EditText(this);
        tx[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.8f));
        ex[i].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,0.2f));
        tx[i].setText(listem.get(i).getMalzeme_adi());
        ex[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        llx[i].setId(i);
        llx[i].setClickable(true);
        final int j = i;
        llx[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                msg(tx[j].getText().toString());
            }
        });

        llx[i].addView(tx[i]);
        llx[i].addView(ex[i]);

        ll.addView(llx[i]);
    }

}


private void msg(String x){
    Toast.makeText(this, x, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void cagir(View view){
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.kaydetff:
        for (int i = 0; i < ex.length; i++) {
            if(!ex[i].getText().toString().equals("")){
                Log.e(tx[i].getText().toString(),ex[i].getText().toString());
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}
}
```